# How to know what encoding to use when reading files?

Tags: node.js, http, encoding, utf-8, fs

When reading an image file what encoding should I be using? I'm building a basic server to serve up a html file with an image and when I read the image file with the encoding of 'utf-8' and send the data to the browser, the browser doesn't receive the image. However, if I set the encoding to an empty string(i.e. {encoding: ''}), the browser receives the image. Also, when I look at the read stream object it says that the default encoding is 'utf-8', which makes me wonder why setting the encoding to 'utf-8' doesn't work?

Here's the piece of code that doesn't work:

```
let readStream = fs.createReadStream('./static/002.jpg', {flags: 'r', encoding: 'utf8'})
    console.log('ReadStream: ',  readStream)
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
    readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        res.write(chunk)
    })

    readStream.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

    readStream.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Image stream ended')
        res.end()
    })

    readStream.on('close', function(){
        console.log("Image Stream closed")
    })
```

And here's the piece of code that does work:

```
let readStream = fs.createReadStream('./static/002.jpg', {flags: 'r', encoding: ''})
        console.log('ReadStream: ',  readStream)
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
        readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
            res.write(chunk)
        })

    readStream.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

    readStream.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Image stream ended')
        res.end()
    })

    readStream.on('close', function(){
        console.log("Image Stream closed")
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that JPEG image is a *binary* file, which means that it is a sequence of plain bytes. `encoding` setting is used when reading *text* files. if you don't specify `encoding` or pass `null`, you'll get a raw stream of bytes, that is exactly what you need to transfer binary data.

[Documentation for a Readable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_setencoding_encoding)  says that if no encoding is provided, `Buffer` object is returned instead of string. This is the reason why default buffer encoding `utf8` is not applied.

See for additional info:

1. [Node.js v8.5.0 Documentation: Buffers and Character Encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings)